# lambda function to find if values are boolean

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have the following DF:

```
is_bool

True
False
NaN
foo
3
```

I am looking to do validation on this column using pandas_schema.  Here is the function I've written which I think is incorrect:

```
        def check_bool(byte):
            try:
                bool(byte)
            except ValueError:
                return False
            return True
        bool_validation = [CustomElementValidation(
            lambda b: check_bool(b), 'Value is not is boolean format')]
```

The output is supposed to tell when a value is not True Or False:

```
row 2 is 'Value is not is boolean format'
row 3 is 'Value is not is boolean format'
row 4 is 'Value is not is boolean format'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pandas.Series.apply`:

```
>>> df.is_bool.apply(isinstance, args = (bool,))

0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
Name: is_bool, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead `try-except` is possible use `isinstance` with `bool`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'is_bool':['', True, False, np.nan, 'foo', 3]})

def check_bool(x):
    return isinstance(x, bool)

print (df['is_bool'].apply(check_bool))
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
Name: is_bool, dtype: bool
```